# complexity calculation and logic concept

Tags: function, time-complexity

I'm trying to findthe complexity of the following code, and I don't know if I'm using my logic right, please correct me if I made a mistake

1)

```
For a = 1 to N
    j = v
    j = j / 2    
    k = i
    While k >= 1
        do some kind of processing
        k = k / 2     // integer division
```

2)

```
For i = 1 to N

        d = d / 2    // integer division
    k = i
    While k >= 1

        k = k-1
```

This one should also be N * log N?

3)

```
For i = 1 to N                  functiontwo(x)
    call functiontwo(i)           if (x <= 0)
                                    return some value
```

This one should be also n * log N, or am I wrong, because it is calling function two, and function two is log n?

Please let me know if I did the right way or give advice on figure out the loop logic better, thank you.

Comment: 2) should be `O(N^2)`. For 3), is `x` an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I haven't done these in a while, but since nobody else has jumped in yet, my two cents are hopefully better than nothing.)

I believe your logic is sound on #1. The i loop should be O(N), and the j and k loops appear to be O(logN), making the overall O(NlogN).

I question your conclusion on #2, though. Since k is decremented by one instead of divided, it seems to me that the k loop would be O(N), making for O(N^2) overall.

Hmmm...#3 is weird. I see why your first thought is O(NlogN). The division ordinarily would make it analagous to #1. Except... the first argument sent to `functiontwo` will be a positive value from the i loop. Since x > 0, it will then call `functiontwo` with half the original argument, which is still positive. Which will happen again, and again, etc. The mathematician in me starts to think that will never end. But I suppose one could argue that eventually you will reach the limit of the precision of your numeric data type and eventually have the result of x/2 be so close to zero that the computer counts it as zero. In that case, I imagine O(NlogN) would be accurate.

BTW, my answer for #3 is assuming that the x/2 is not integer division since you specified it for the others, but not for this one.

Comment: if the loop are not nested together, I take the biggest one?